# JavaScript in Wordpress - Scope issue

Tags: javascript, wordpress, scope

I can't figure out why my basic JavaScript is not working on a local server with Wordpress installed.

I have this in my main.js which gets bundled to bundle.js:

```
const test = 'this is a test';
console.log(test);
```

In my functions.php I enqueued the script:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/js/bundle.js' , array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
```

Once I load the site, test gets logged and I get 'this is a test'. But when I want to access the variable test in the console, I get a reference error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM17626:1
```

What am I missing here? I've tried to search for an answer, but this is so basic, I couldn't find anything about it. How can I get a reference error, when test is declared globally?

Comment: Normally when I see `bundle.js`, this implies it's been compiled with Babel / Webpack etc, is this the case?, if so your using modules, and `const test`, won't create a global var.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know this. I am new to these bundlers. I've just tried to import a module which declares a variable and then logs it. It works, but I still can't access the variable in the console. This means when using bundlers etc. there are no global variables?

Comment: Generally global vars is something you want to try and avoid,  but if you want to say expose a variable to the global, you can do something like ->  `window.test = test`

Comment: thank you very much for making everythign clear to me, cheers